# Threading: Second thread doesn't run in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, class, parallel-processing

I'm working with threading for the first time and somehow it doesn't work. When I start the first thread it starts but the second one doesn't. After a bit of debugging I noticed that the problem is that because thread 1 has an infinite loop, the other one waits until the first one stops. However, I want them to run in parallel.

Code:

Main Script

```
com = Communication("RPI", "192.168.2.156")
water = Water(com)

t_com = threading.Thread(target= com.server())
t_water = threading.Thread(target=water.main())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting")
    t_com.start()
    t_water.start()
```

Communication: Here the program is getting stuck

```
class Communication:
    def __init__(self, clientName, serverAddress):
        print("Com")
        self.mqttClient = mqtt.Client(clientName)
        self.mqttClient.connect(serverAddress, 1883)

        self.stunde = None
        self.minute = None
        self.active = False
        self.time_to_water = None
        self.dauer = None

    def server(self): <!-- a necessary infinity loop -->
        print("Thread1 activated")
        self.mqttClient.on_connect = self.connectionStatus
        self.mqttClient.on_message = self.messageDecoder
        self.mqttClient.loop_forever()
```

Water: This Thread doesn't start but should

```
class Water:
    def __init__(self, com):
        print("Water")
        self.sensoren = Sensoren(pinRain=22, pinVent1=17, pinVent2=27)
        self.com = com

    def main(self):
        print("Thread2 activated")
        while True:
```

In the first Version of my programm `Water` and `Communication` weren't classes, but a mix of many functions. There the above code in `main.py` worked.

Comment: `threading.Thread(target= com.server())` and `threading.Thread(target=water.main())` should be `threading.Thread(target= com.server)` and `threading.Thread(target=water.main)`. You're calling the function, then passing the return result to `Thread`.

Comment: you will never get true parallel processing with python threading. use multi processing instead

Comment: @Dunski a fair point, although it should be clarified that that's not the issue here. The point of using multiprocessing is to avoid things like [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: Agreed @RandomDavis

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks a lot. It works now. But I have a new problem which is i think related. I write the question under the answer of Andres

Comment: Please only ask one question per question. If you have a new, different question, please post it as a new question, along with what debugging you've done to solve it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your threads there shouldn't be parentheses on the parameter to target. You are calling the function and then (which in this case is never) passing the result of that function as an argument, instead you should pass the function to be called (only the name, without parentheses).

To answer the question on the title, the Python interpreter only allows execution of one single thread at a time due to the Global Interpreter Lock, as far as I know it's used primarily for memory safety but it won't allow true parallelism from pure Python.
You can still do parallel tasks using multiproccess or a compiled C function (at least on CPython) since those can bypass the GIL, but you'll have to manage your own locks in case more than one thread access the same data.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock

https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

https://realpython.com/python-gil/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2yeB94CxVQ

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the problem. But now I have an other problem. The while-loop in water.main needs around 1:30 minutes to start again. I don't know why. Might you have an answer?

Comment: Found the answer. Is not related to the topic of this question  so nervermind